# Multiple ajax calls at single instance if scrolled to certain div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create an infinite scrolling page which contains posts. I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="c" id="adata">
<!-- the posts goes here -->
</div>
<div class="card" id="scroll-to">
<div class="ajax-load text-center" style="display:none">
<p><img src="/img/loader.gif">Loading More post</p>
</div></div>
</div>
```

When the user scrolls to the div with `id="scroll-to"`. I have created an ajax call to a code which automatically appends the data to div which have `id="adata"`.

To create the ajax call, I have used the jquery code as follows:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
       hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
            var last_id = $(".box:last").attr("id");
                    $('.ajax-load').show();
            loadMoreData(last_id);
        }
    });

    function loadMoreData(last_id){
      $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/loadMoreData.php?last_id=' + last_id,
                type: "get",
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                if(data.html == " "){
                    $('.ajax-load').html("No more records found");
                    return;
                }
                $('.ajax-load').hide();
                $('#adata').append(data);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                  alert('server not responding...');
            });
    }
```

But, whenever the user scrolls to the div with `id="scroll-to"`, the jquery code above creates multiple ajax calls at the same/single instance to the URL `/loadMoreData.php?last_id=' + last_id` with `last_id` replaced as the id of the last post.

Suppose the id of the last post is 2177, the jquery code creates multiple ajax requests to the URL `/loadMoreData.php?last_id=2177`, which really shouldn't be more than once and can't seem to understand why?

Due to the multiple requests with same `last_id`, the posts get repeated. What is the ideal solution to this problem?

To understand the problem better, you can visit http://funpd.com/index1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement kind of 'watchdog' for your requests - create boolean variable and check for it when you're about to perform request, simple example:

```
var isDownloading = false;

function loadMoreData(last_id) {
    if (isDownloading) return;
    isDownloading = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/loadMoreData.php?last_id=' + last_id,
        type: "get",
    }).done(function(data) {
        isDownloading = false;
        if (data.html == " ") {
            $('.ajax-load').html("No more records found");
            return;
        }
        $('.ajax-load').hide();
        $('#adata').append(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        isDownloading = false;
        alert('server not responding...');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like expected behaviour, since the page will still be scrolled to below the divs you are reaching. The AJAX will not be completed, and thus appending html instantly.

Put an if statement before the loadMoreData, checking if the ajax is loading, reset the checking var on done for example.